# Rails 3.1 distinct find and missing attributes

Tags: activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-3.1, distinct

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

I'm trying to list all states, and their respective cities, that contain at least one company registered. My first try was the following query:

```
states = State.joins(:cities => :companies).includes(:cities)
```

Which works, but I end up getting duplicates if a state has more than one city with companies in it. I then changed the query to:

```
states = State.joins(:cities => :companies).includes(:cities).select("distinct(states.id)")
```

This query almost works. I have access to the cities (states[0].cities), and there are no duplicates, but if I try to access an attribute from the State object, I get the following error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :056 >states[0].name
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: name
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement overrides the default (`SELECT * FROM ...` becomes `SELECT distinct(state.id) FROM...`) so the results don't include the columns of your state table (where the attributes are inferred from).  Try changing your select method to the following:

```
.select("distinct(states.id), states.*")
```

Comment: You don't need the [SOLVED] tag, just "check" this answer ;)

Comment: Ops, my bad. Should have read the F.A.Q. on asking questions first, just noticed it has instructions on this ^^.