# Query for distinct instance of model + one other field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, distinct

I have a model called `Evaluation`. When an `evaluation` is created, an `eval_number` is created with it.  There are many `evaluations` with the same `eval_number`.

Here's an example:

```
- !ruby/object:Evaluation
  attributes:
    id: 2023
    score: 3
    created_at: 2013-09-08 13:10:53.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-08 13:10:53.000000000 Z
    student_id: 26
    goal_id: 50
    eval_number: 33
- !ruby/object:Evaluation
  attributes:
    id: 2099
    score: 4
    created_at: 2013-09-08 13:19:12.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-08 13:19:12.000000000 Z
    student_id: 26
    goal_id: 36
    eval_number: 34
- !ruby/object:Evaluation
  attributes:
    id: 2100
    score: 3
    created_at: 2013-09-08 13:19:12.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-08 13:19:12.000000000 Z
    student_id: 26
    goal_id: 37
    eval_number: 34
- !ruby/object:Evaluation
  attributes:
    id: 2101
    score: 4
    created_at: 2013-09-08 13:19:12.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2013-09-08 13:19:12.000000000 Z
    student_id: 26
    goal_id: 38
    eval_number: 34
```

In a view, I want to show the date that a given `evaluation` was created in a table header.  It should look like this:

```
date_1  |  date_2  |  date_3  | date_4  |  etc..
```

To do this, I need to get distinct `evaluation_numbers` + the `created_at` dates that go with them.  I thought that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419577/rails-3-1-distinct-find-and-missing-attributes/7420687#7420687) would help, but it's returning more than one record per `eval_number` with this code:

```
  def eval_date(i)
    evals = self.goals.first.evaluations
    eval = evals.select("distinct(eval_number), created_at").all[i]
    eval.created_at.to_date
  end
```

It seems like distinct `eval_number`s are being selected, but *also* distinct `created_at` columns (which of course are all different).  This makes the `.all[i]` basically useless as it's finding the `[0], [1], [2], etc` element correctly - but there are far more than whatever the given number of `i` is in the returned array.

I want to find a distinct `eval_number` and load only the `created_date` that goes with it.  I think I could load the whole record with all attributes, but I don't need them, so I'd rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 def eval_date(i)
    evals = self.goals.first.evaluations
    eval = evals.order("eval_number").group(:eval_number).all[i]
    eval.created_at.to_date
 end
```

PS: if you are calling `eval_date` repeatedly then cache the evaluations like so

```
 def eval_date(i)
    @evals ||= self.goals.first.evaluations.order("eval_number").group("eval_number").all
    eval = @evals[i]
    eval.created_at.to_date
 end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - should `eval = evals[i]` be eval = @evals[i]?

Answer (score 0):

got it working like this, but i'm open to better suggestions:

```
  #student.rb  
  def eval_date(i)
    eval = self.goals.first.evals_by_number.values[i].first
    eval.created_at.strftime("%d %b, %Y")
  end

  #goal.rb
  def evals_by_number
    self.evaluations.order("eval_number").group_by(&:eval_number)    
  end
```